# If work is given by the $1$-form $3dx+4dy-dz$, find all points that can be reached from the origin without work

Tags: differential-forms

I have no idea how to approach this question. There's no mention of how "work" functions in my notes.
As an attempt I listed the points $$(\pm3, \pm4,\pm1)$$ but it's a guess.

Comment: Work is a product of force and displacement. So I am guessing you're supposed to find out points where it integrates back to $0$. Also please use MathJax in the title, as without it there is very limited amount of help you'll get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: You want points $P$ so that $\int_0^P 3\,dx+4\,dy-dz = 0$. Note first that the integral is path-independent. Why? Indeed, you can find a function $f$ so that $df = 3\,dx+4\,dy-dz$, and then the integral is equal to $f(P)-f(0)$.